# EXPO upload:ios Doesn't Take New Builds

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ios, testflight

I have been building my managed expo RN project via `expo build:ios` for the last year with the appropriate version and then incrementing the build number. When I want to send it to TestFlight I do `expo upload:ios --app-name MyAppName` and it gets uploaded as a new build to the same version in the app store. It takes 2 days to approve a new version in the AppStore so having to push a new version for every single little update is inefficient. This is why builds are so helpful.

As of the last few months I haven't been able to run `expo upload:ios --app-name MyAppName` anymore. I am forced to use the Transporter app and the Transporter app makes me upload a new version every single time. This is really setting me behind in my timeline.

I have read a few articles saying that something was discontinued with `expo upload` but I was curious if there was a way around it? How is everyone else pushing their minor changes to TestFlight without having to increment the version number?

My expo diagnostics:

```
Expo CLI 4.0.4 environment info:
System:
  OS: macOS 11.1
  Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node: 15.3.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
  Yarn: 1.22.10 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
  npm: 7.0.14 - /usr/local/bin/npm
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms: iOS 14.3, DriverKit 20.2, macOS 11.1, tvOS 14.3, watchOS 7.2
  Android SDK:
    API Levels: 29, 30
    Build Tools: 30.0.2
    System Images: android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-30 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 4.1 AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283
  Xcode: 12.3/12C33 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
  expo: ^40.0.0 => 40.0.0 
  react: ^17.0.1 => 17.0.1 
  react-dom: ^17.0.1 => 17.0.1 
  react-native: ^0.63.4 => 0.63.4 
  react-navigation: ^3.0.0 => 3.13.0 
npmGlobalPackages:
  expo-cli: 4.0.4
Expo Workflow: managed
```

terminal output:

```
Uploading the app to Testflight, hold tight...
There was an error while trying to write to Gemfile.lock. It is likely that 
you need to allow write permissions for the file at path: 
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/dist/lib/vendor/Gemfile.lock
[09:27:54]: Login to App Store Connect (admin@myemail.com)
[09:27:56]: Login successful
[09:27:59]: Ready to upload new build to TestFlight (App: 123456789)...
[09:28:02]: Going to upload updated app to App Store Connect
[09:28:02]: This might take a few minutes. Please don't interrupt the script.
[09:28:02]: [iTMSTransporter] -Djava.ext.dirs=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/itms/java/lib/ext is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.

[09:28:02]: [iTMSTransporter] Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

[09:28:02]: [iTMSTransporter] Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

[09:28:02]: iTunes Transporter output above ^
[09:28:02]: The call to the iTMSTransporter completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.
Failed to upload the standalone app to the App Store.
We recommend using Transporter.app (​https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874555​) instead of the expo upload:ios command if you have any trouble with it.
Error uploading ipa file, for more information see above
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/dist/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.146.1/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/interface.rb:141:in `user_error!'
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/dist/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.146.1/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/ui.rb:17:in `method_missing'
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/dist/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.146.1/pilot/lib/pilot/build_manager.rb:37:in `upload'
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/dist/lib/app/pilot_upload.rb:20:in `block in <main>'
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/dist/lib/app/funcs.rb:4:in `with_captured_stderr'
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/dist/lib/app/pilot_upload.rb:12:in `<main>'
Error: Error uploading ipa file, for more information see above
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/dist/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.146.1/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/interface.rb:141:in `user_error!'
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/dist/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.146.1/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/ui.rb:17:in `method_missing'
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/dist/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.146.1/pilot/lib/pilot/build_manager.rb:37:in `upload'
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/dist/lib/app/pilot_upload.rb:20:in `block in <main>'
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/dist/lib/app/funcs.rb:4:in `with_captured_stderr'
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/dist/lib/app/pilot_upload.rb:12:in `<main>'
    at runFastlaneAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/upload/utils.ts:64:11)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
    at IOSUploader._uploadToTheStore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/upload/IOSUploader.ts:196:5)
    at IOSUploader.upload (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/upload/BaseUploader.ts:36:5)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/upload.ts:124:9
    at Command.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/exp.ts:346:7)
```